# Constructor Invocation using Dynamic Linq Select Expression

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, constructor, invocation

I'm using [Dynamic Linq](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/GettingStarted#invocations).

I can do the following:

```
IQueryable<Person>().Select("new(Id as Id, FirstName + Surname as Name");
```

This creates an `IQueryable` (**not** an `IQueryable<object>`) containing an anonymous type.

But given I have the following class:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public ListItem()
    {
    }
    public ListItem(int id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to select directly into this type from my `IQueryable<Person>` by invoking the constructor of `ListItem`, equivalent to the following:

```cs
IQueryable<Person>().Select(p => new ListItem(p.Id, p.FirstName + p.Surname));
```

I've tried variants such as:

```
// Illegal - new expects form "new()" - exception "'(' expected"
IQueryable<Person>().Select("new ListItem(Id, FirstName + Surname)");

// this doesn't work, "No property 'ListItem' exists on type 'Person'"
IQueryable<Person>().Select("ListItem(Id, FirstName + Surname)");

// this doesn't work because "[" is not expected
IQueryable<Person>().Select("[MyProject.Utils.ListItem,MyProject]()");
```

I believe this to be possible from the documentation [available here](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/GettingStarted#invocations):

> Overload resolution for methods, constructors, and indexers uses rules similar to C#. In informal terms, overload resolution will pick the best matching method, constructor, or indexer, or report an ambiguity error if no single best match can be identified.
>
> Note that constructor invocations are not prefixed by new.

Is this possible or have I misunderstood the documentation?

Comment: Why use DynamicLinq for this instead of just LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if constructors are supported in the `Select` method in Dynamic Linq. Maybe the documentation is saying that this is only supported for predicates, like the expressions that are used in the `Where` method. I am not sure though.

Anyway, this might be a solution for you:

```
var result =
    context
        .Customers
        .Select("new(Id as Id, FirstName + Surname as Name")
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => new ListItem(x.Id, x.Name))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I have used a similar approach, but since the type of the object in the first `Select` is dynamically generated, you can't refer to `x.Id`.
You'd need instead to use something like AutoMapper, e.g.
`.Select(x => AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<ListItem>())`.

Comment: The result of `Select(...).AsEnumerable()` is `IEnumerable<dynamic>` which means that you can use `x.Id`. You won't get intellisense, but the code will compile and run correctly. I actually tried this before posting the answer.

Comment: Whoops! I'd forgotten about `dynamic`. Thanks - I think the answer to my question is that you have to do an explicit conversion step, and that dynamic linq doesn't by default support instantiating particular types.